# How to stagger animations and trigger two animations simultaneously on each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have 3 text boxes. They are hidden by default, and I need them to simultaneously fade in and slide down 40px on DOM load. They also need to be "staggered" such that after the element finishes it's animations the next one triggers.

Here is the relevant js:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  "Use Strict"
  var outerFunction = function(dropIn, time, offset) {  
    $(dropIn).each(function() {
      var me =   $(this);
      var mejo = $(this).children('.drop-in-text-opacity-wrap');
      setTimeout(function() {
        me.css({'margin-bottom': 0});
        mejo.fadeIn(1000);
      },time)
      time = time + offset;
    }) 
  }
  outerFunction('.drop-in-text', 0, 500)
});
```

and a [working example on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPRVKw)

As you can see I'm most of the way to a solution but when the second and third iterations start, the pevious elements jump back to their original position (though the css doesn't change back when this happens per the inspector).

I've looked at all kinds of answers here on SO using:

```
.dequeue(),
animate({//some code},{queue: false}),
.stop()
etc
```

But I'm not getting any love. I'd be grateful for any insight!

Comment: I don't have time to check it but I recommend you to use velocity.js to achieve your goal in 1 line of code.

Comment: GSAP would do it too but I have constraints. Native JS + jQuery only. Thanks for suggestion though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes I made:

CSS:

1. Removed margin from `drop-in-text`.
2. Added `translateY(-40px)` to it.

JS:

1. Changed `margin-bottom: 0` to `transform: translateZ (0) translateY(0)`

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVErOd)

Comment: That's brilliant! I feel like I should have thought of that since I was translating Z axis for mobile anyway but great solution!